# How to print a dataframe in oneline without including None?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe

```
     0 1 2 3
   A b a p l
   C c p g None
   T g t x None
```

Right now I'm printing it like following

```
   for i in range(len(df.columns)): print((df[i]).to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
b
c
g
a
p
t
p
g
x
  l
None
None
```

Is there a way to print it like this?

```
 bcgaptpgxl
```

Comment: Can you included code to initialize the dataframe? It helps future readers if they can just copy/paste to run your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `None` is actually a `NaN`:

```
>>> ''.join(df.melt()['value'].dropna().tolist())
'bcgaptpgxl'
```

Comment: Great answer. Could add `''.join([v for v in df.melt()["value"].tolist() if v is not None])` if `None` _is_ `None`. (or `if v != "None"`) if its literally the string "None".

Comment: Or `''.join([str(v) for v in df.melt()["value"] if pd.notnull(v) and v != 'None'])`